# Connecting and Adding of One Extension template inside of Another extension template ? in typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

Is there any way to do to include one extension template (Html ) inside of another extension template (Html file)  without affecting the functionality.

Eg:  I have 2 extensions inside of a website '**ext_included**' with '**N_includefile.html**' template and '**ext_package**' with '**N_package.html**' respectively,i need to use the N_includefile.html inside of 'N_package.html'
is there any way to do this??

Anyone know about this?is there any possibility to do this

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box but can be achieved by 2 ways:

#### 1) Adopt the structure of your `partialRootPaths`.

Adopt the TS to have something like this

```
plugin.tx_ext1.view.partialRootPaths {
  10 = EXT:ext1/Resources/Private/Partials/
  20 = EXT:sitePackage/Resources/Private/GlobalPartials/
}
plugin.tx_ext2.view.partialRootPaths {
  10 = EXT:ext2/Resources/Private/Partials/
  20 = EXT:sitePackage/Resources/Private/GlobalPartials/
}
```

and then you can use the same partials

#### 2) Use EXT:fluid_components

Using the extension [EXT:fluid_components](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/fluid_components) makes it possible to organize your templates in a better way with atoms, molecules and you can even create an automated styleguide with [EXT:fluid_styleguide](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/fluid_styleguide)

Comment: Is it possible to add without  using extensions

Comment: sorry don't understand the comment

Comment: Possible but not recommended. In earlier days people putted this stuff in `fileadmin/`.

Comment: So which is the easier way to achieve that?  'Adopt the structure of your partialRootPath' or  'Use EXT:fluid_components'?

Comment: @nito how can we do this inside fileadmin/ ?

Comment: @GeorgRinger can i understand it with an example,because i didnt much familier with these files

Comment: @Dev_fan NOT RECOMMENDED! just to answer a question: create a subfolder and file of your choice e.g. `fileadmin/template/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript` and put your snippet from Georg 1) in it. replace `20 = EXT:sitepackage/...` with `20 = FILE:fileadmin/...` Go to the backend > choose the module `Template` on the left side > Choose the page in the Page Tree that holds your Page Tamplate > Choose `Info/modify` in the selectbox > click on Setup > Insert: `<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/template/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript">` > clear caches.

Comment: Hi, @GeorgRinger I have gotten the 'N_includefile.html' inside of 'N_package.html'.

But the problem is i didn't get the variable values used 'N_includefile.html' file. so how can i get that

eg:'{data.description}'  
 <h2 class="test-client__need-help-title">h{data.description}</h2>

Comment: you must provide that to the partial as argument